# Why does the $\mathbb{1}$ in $S = \mathbb{1} + i \mathcal{M}$ correspond to no scattering?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I am a beginner in quantum field theory and I am learning from the [lecture notes by David Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html). On Page 58, he gives an example of two nucleons scattering and says that we are only interested in $\langle f|S-1|i\rangle$ since this is the only relevant quantum amplitude for scattering events. I do not understand how subtracting $\langle f|i \rangle$ from $\langle f|S|i \rangle$ will exclude the non-scattering events and give us what we are looking for.

Comment: The operator that you call $M$ is usually denoted by $T$. This is just a way to separate the non-trivial part of the $S$-matrix, since $\langle \alpha \vert 1 \vert \beta \rangle=0 $ if $\vert \alpha \rangle \perp \vert \beta\rangle$.

Comment: @pppqqq NB: It's me that called it $\mathcal M$; I re-wrote the title since the question is not about nucleon scattering, and it is denoted by $T$ or $\mathcal M$, such as for example in Schwarz, or even $\mathcal A$. In hindsight, it would have been most appropriate to write it as $\mathcal A$ in the title, as this is what Tong uses later on, which the OP is reading.

Answer (score 2):

The decomposition $S=1+i\mathcal M$ is just a convenient way to separate out the "trivial" part of the $S$-matrix.

Recall that two quantum states are orthogonal if and only if there exists, at least in principle, a measurement which can distinguish beetween the two. Therefore the $1$ in $S=1+i\mathcal M$ is zero if "something happens":$$\langle \alpha \vert 1 \vert \beta \rangle =0 \iff \vert \alpha \rangle \perp \vert \beta \rangle.$$

Note that $\mathcal M$ satisfies the identities: $$\mathcal M^\dagger \mathcal M+i (\mathcal M-\mathcal M^\dagger)=0\\\mathcal M \mathcal M^\dagger +i (\mathcal M^\dagger-\mathcal M)=0$$which are equivalent to the unitarity of the $S$-matrix and ultimately lead to the optical theorem, see for example Weinberg S., "The quantum theory of fields, Vol.1".

---

Side note. As pointed out, there are several notations for the so called "transfer matrix" $S-1$. The one I encounter more frequently is $S=1+iT$.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I do not understand why two quantum states are orthogonal if and only if a measurement can distinguish between the two. What does it mean to distinguish between the two states ?

Comment: What I mean is that if the system is prepared into state $\vert \alpha \rangle$ XOR into state $\vert \beta \rangle$, you can in principle perform an experiment which determines the state ($\alpha$ or $\beta$) with certainty. In other words, there exists an *observable* $A$ which has value $1$ in the state $\vert \alpha \rangle$ and value $0$ in the state $\vert \beta \rangle$. (The observable might be $A=\vert \alpha \rangle \langle \alpha \vert$)

Comment: How does this relate to orthogonality ? Do you know of any resource where I could read more about this ?

Comment: Do you agree with me that if it is possible, in a **single** experiment, to determine whether the system is in state $\alpha$ or $\beta$, then there must exist an observable for which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues? This comes from the basic postulates of quantum mechanics. Now, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues, they are automatically orthogonal. All this is discussed, for example, in the first chapter of Sakurai, "Modern Quantum Mechanics".

Comment: I agree that if in a single experiment, we can determine that the state is $\alpha$ and also that it is not in state $\beta$ (by whatever means necessary), then the rest is as you said.

So, how do we know that the initial state $  |i>$ is orthogonal to the final state $  |f>$ when there is scattering ? Are they distinct eigenstates of an operator ? If so, which operator and how do we know the eigenstates are distinct ?

Comment: For example, the in and out state could be states with definite (different) momentums. In general you have an in state $\vert \alpha (-\infty)\rangle$ and you want to know how does $\vert \alpha (+\infty) \rangle=S\vert \alpha (-\infty)\rangle$ look like in the distant future (states are in the interaction picture). If *you* choose to project $\vert \alpha(\infty)\rangle$ on a state $\vert \beta \rangle $ physically distinguishable from $\vert \alpha (-\infty)\rangle$, then the only operator which plays a role is $S-1$. If it's not clear, maybe we could continue in the chatroom?